# How to change JoomShopping URLs?

Tags: plugin, url, .htaccess-configuration, alias

I have added several JoomShopping categories with respective pages. However, they have long URLs:

`http://ysadba.kiev.ua/component/jshopping/CATEGORY/PRODUCT.html?Itemid=0`

I'd like them to look like this:

`http://ysadba.kiev.ua/CATEGORY/PRODUCT.html`

I tried to use the following .htaccess configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/single-room([a-z0-9./-]*)$
RewriteRule single-room([a-z0-9./-]*) component/jshopping/single-room$1 [P]
```

However, I didn't succeed, because this redirects to *file* with this address, while I just need to create some sort of *alias*. Has anyone experienced similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it redirects to the long address; in your case IMHO: you have to write a `router` to supporting SEF URLs in your component.
I think, all you need is described here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component